# Check if element of 2d vector is NULL

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, null-pointer, 2d-vector

So I have a 2d vector of Object pointers which are initialized. Some members have an Object while some are 'empty'

```
Class Obj{int x, y};
std::vector<std::vector<Obj*>> thing;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
 std::vector<Obj*> row(4, 0);
 for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
 {
  if(i%2)
  {
  Obj* obj1 = new Obj();
  row.push_back(obj1);
  }
  else
  {
  row.push_back(NULL);
  }
 thing.push_back(row);
}
```

So when I go to check:

```
if(thing[i][j] != NULL)
```

I get an segmentation fault if it's empty. So how do I check the element in the 2d vector?
Because

```
if(thing != NULL)
```

doesn't work it gives me the errors:

```
comparison between NULL and non-pointer ('std::vector<std::vector<Field *> >' and NULL) [-Wnull-arithmetic]
invalid operands to binary expression ('std::vector<std::vector<Field *> >' and 'long')
```

while

```
if(thing.at(i).at(j) != NULL)
```

would give me an out of range error
when i and j are the same values throughout

Comment: `if (i < thing.size() && j < thing[i].size() && thing[i][j] != nullptr)`?

Comment: I ommitted it here but I do check that in the original code. the problem is the moment I try anything with thing[i][j] I get an segmentation fault

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And have you used a debugger to catch the crash so you can locate exactly where in your code it happens, and check the values of all involved variables at that point?

Comment: for one thing you need to put the `thing.push_back` in the right place, it is now in the inner loop, I guess you meant the outer loop. another thing that I think is not correct is your `push_back` in row, you already created 4 entries in row by the declaration. instead just assign `row[i] = new Object;`

Answer (score 1):

You create ‘row’ vectors in the loop, populate them and let them expire (go out of scope).

You need to push them into ‘thing’ at the end of the loop.

```
thing.push_back(row);
```

Comment: yeah I forgot to add that here. My main problem is accessing a member of thing though

Comment: @SarothNevertale Why are you asking people to look at the code is is NOT what you have? As AndersK commented, it's wrong again. He also explained your other issue.